# How to perform action on popup. it's displayed randomly in between of some actions? Selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
case "single select type":
radioButtonStatus = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'Single select type')]")).isDisplayed();
Random random=new Random();
int number=random.nextInt(5);
if(number==0)
{
  number=number+1;
}
if (radioButtonStatus)
{
  System.out.println("RadioButton"+number);
  webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("path["+number+"]path/*[1]")).click();
  Exam.clickOnSaveandNextButton();
}
break;
```

I have written a loop with a switch case. If the loop is 60 times then the popup will appear in between the loop at different points.

Answer (score 0):

option one - try/catch block:

```
    try {
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
    }
    catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {

    }
```

option two - using `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions`:

```
if (ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent() != null) {
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
}
```